# PHP array of tree with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have problem with make automatic tree of arrays in PHP. Ex. i have numbers in my array: 2, 3, 3, and i can manulally make tree.

```
<?
$source_arr = array(2,3,3);

for($x=0; $x<$source_arr[0]; $x++){ // level 0: 2 loops

for ($xx=0; $xx<$source_arr[1]; $xx++) {  // level 1: 3 loops

    for ($xxx=0; $xxx<$source_arr[2]; $xxx++) {  // level 2: 3 loops

        $new[] = "$x$xx$xxx";

   }    
    }
}   

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000
    [1] => 001
    [2] => 002
    [3] => 010
    [4] => 011
    [5] => 012
    [6] => 020
    [7] => 021
    [8] => 022
    [9] => 100
    [10] => 101
    [11] => 102
    [12] => 110
    [13] => 111
    [14] => 112
    [15] => 120
    [16] => 121
    [17] => 122
)
```

But i want to automate it, i have different numbers of levels arrays with different values, like this: 11 levels:

```
$source_arr = array(8,5,10,12,5,8,12,5,6,10,8);
```

And i want to  build automatic large tree. Is it possible with PHP array_walk or array_walk_recursive ? I found posts about building recursive categories tree, but i can not adapt those codes.

edit: i do not want to do infinity array and achieve memory exhaustion. My array count is never larger than 15 items, values range: 3-16.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: First, your result is not a tree; it's a flat array containing all the combinations.  Is that what you're looking for?  
Second, do you really need to store all of the possible combinations (in your example, 5,529,600,000 of them) in memory, or do you just need to loop over them and do something for each one?

Comment: @user1708401 can i just ask what the tree would be used for ??

Comment: You are just getting set dispositions.

Comment: Clearly defined problems like that are absolutely fun to solve. No one could stop me from implementing cool solutions for that problem (in fact I'll probably do this just for fun). I suggest that you keep on trying until you find at least one working solution - the high is worth it.

Comment: I want to acheive long strings of values like presented result in my post. Memory should be enough, it is for several users, on internal server. My array count is never larger than 15 items, values range: 3-16.

Comment: @vstm this might be an interesting exercise, but those nested loops give me the sneaking suspicion that there is a real world problem behind this that is being solved the wrong way. Better to get more details about the actual problem than cause nightmares for an innocent programmer who might inherit this code in a year.

Comment: @Mark Reed He is not building a tree but he is iterating a tree. After all, his $source_arr is an abstraction of a very special tree.

Comment: @Syntax Error this problem looks like another one: finding the probabilities that by casting some dices which could have different number of faces, the sum of these dices is equal to some integer. This is the multinomial distribution, but you can compute it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Iterating through trees have to be done recursively. There is no choice since tree depth is unbounded but your loop nesting level is fixed. You are not building the tree, but the construction of your list is indeed a tree traversal. Your recursive function must have the following parameters :

- an identification of the current node, here, we can just use the level of the node and the prefix string built from its parent ;
- the size of each level of the tree, which can be retrieve from your list of array source_arr and the current level already provided ;
- the array being built

The result could also have been produced by return and merge, but it wouldn't be more simple and it would be less efficient.

```
<?php

function build(array &$sizes, array &$result, $prefix, $level)
{
  if ($level == count($sizes)) {
    $result[] = $prefix;
  }
  else {
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $sizes[$level] ; $i++) {
      build($sizes, $result, $prefix . $i, $level + 1);
    }
  }
}


$sizes = array(8,5,10,12);
$result = array();
build($sizes, $result, '', 0);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Note that the tree you are requesting is huge, and PHP will run out of memory before being able to print the result.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I wanted. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that seems to be working. It's not very clean, I know. But hey! There's no recursion! ;)

```
<?php

function generate(array $a) {
  $multArray = function($mult, $e) {
    return $mult * $e;
  };

  $finalSize = array_reduce($a, $multArray, 1);

  $res = array();
  $aReverse = array_reverse($a);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $finalSize; $i++) {
    $tmpReverseRes = array();
    foreach ($aReverse as $k => $v) {
      $mult = array_reduce(array_slice($aReverse, 0, $k), $multArray, 1);
      $tmpReverseRes[] = (int)($i / $mult) % $v;
    }
    $res[] = join('', array_reverse($tmpReverseRes));
  }

  return $res;
}

$a = array(2, 3, 3);

print_r(generate($a));
```

**update:**

We can also implement that with a class:

```
<?php
class StrangeGenerator {
  private $a = null;
  private $aReverse = null;
  private $combinationsCount = null;

  public function __construct(array $array) {
    $this->a = $array;
    $this->aReverse = array_reverse($array);
    $this->combinationsCount = array_reduce($array, 'self::multArray', 1);
  }

  public function getCombinationFor($index) {
    $this->checkRange($index);

    $revRes = array();
    foreach ($this->aReverse as $k => $v) {
      $mult = array_reduce(array_slice($this->aReverse, 0, $k), 'self::multArray', 1);
      $revRes[] = (int)($index / $mult) % $v;
    }
    return join('', array_reverse($revRes));
  }

  public function getCombinationsCount() {
    return $this->combinationsCount;
  }

  protected function checkRange($index) {
    if ($index < 0 || $index >= $this->combinationsCount) {
      throw new RangeException('Out of range');
    }
  }

  protected static function multArray($mult, $e) {
    return $mult * $e;
  }
}

$a = array(2, 3, 3);

$g = new StrangeGenerator($a);

$count = $g->getCombinationsCount();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $res = $g->getCombinationFor($i);
  echo "$res\n";
}
```

Btw, this class does not keep all the combinations in the memory. They're calculated on demand instead.